# Parameters Still Exists After Shutting Down All Nodes In Docker?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a continuation of [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/350792/parameter-server-and-persistence/)

It does make sense to me that the built-in parameter server should not persist after shutting down the ROS Master.

However, I am only using the built-in ROS parameter server, and  I can still see parameters and their values after I shut down all nodes launched by a single launch file (by Ctrl-C).

Then, to see if the ROS Master has really been shut down, I used `$rostopic list` and saw `\rosout` and several other topics. However I could not get anything from `\rosout` when I tried to echo it. Therefore, I am not sure if the ROS Master has really been shut down.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361410/parameters-still-exists-after-shutting-down-all-nodes-in-docker?/) by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Parameters Still Exists After Shutting Down All Nodes In Docker?

if your question is *Do parameters still exist after shutting down all nodes?*, then the answer would be: yes.

The parameter server is part of the Master, so it doesn't matter whether you have nodes running or not.

Docker does not change anything here (unless you have your Master running inside a container and you've shut down *that* container).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on 2020-09-12**:
Nice! Now the question is if Master has really been shutdown by hitting CTRL-C or not. Please [see here](https://answers.ros.org/question/361464/does-roscore-gets-shut-down-after-hitting-ctrl-c-if-started-by-roslaunch/)